# a condition which will not proceed to step unless condition is true

Tags: php, recursion, if-statement, conditional-statements

anyone help...:D
im creating a personal calendar schedule while Im learning PHP. I come across to a part where I need to set a particular condition and then output will only display if condition will be meet. See notes.

$n = 50
$n must not be greater than or equals to 20 [ if ($n >= 20) ]
else { $n - 10 }

will only print if $n less than 20

is this possible??
my friends told me to use recursion however i'm not that familiar with it
still trying to learn.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but you need to show more code on what you want to accomplish. Your question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking about a while-do

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

As per the PHP Manual:

```
 $i = 0;
do {
    echo $i;
 } while ($i > 0);
```

Or:

```
do {
    if ($i < 5) {
        echo "i is not big enough";
        break;
    }
    $i *= $factor;
    if ($i < $minimum_limit) {
        break;
    }
   echo "i is ok";

    /* process i */

} while (0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
if ($n <= 20)
{echo $n}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// $n starts at 50
$n = 50;
// so long as n is above or equal to twenty, subtract 10.
while( $n >= 20 ) $n -= 10;
// at this point, n will *always* be less than 20, so we'll out put it.
// print is one way to output n.
print $n;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what your saying.  You want to deduct 10 from the value of $n until you get below 20?

try:

```
$n = 50;

while($n >= 20){
   $n = $n - 10;
}

echo $n;
```

If $n is less than 20, it will never go into the loop and it will be left alone.

IF $n is greater than 20, it will start deducting 10 and will not preform the echo until $n is less than 20

If you pass in 18, you will echo 18.

If you pass in 50, you will echo 10 (because 20 is still >= 10 so it will deduct once more)

If you pass in 48, you will echo 18

Comment: Thanks a lot 
i did learn a lot
i will bookmark this site
very helpfull